# Yii2 Basic Clear input form after submit button

Tags: forms, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I created a modal to create post and another one to create gallery inside another view and it work perfect but after I click submit my form keeps the data entered even if I refresh the page it's still have the data entered, is it possible to clear form after submit

My view code of post is :

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $ly_addPost app\models\Posts */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="posts-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($ly_addPost, 'Post_title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($ly_addPost, 'Post_text')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($ly_addPost, 'Post_file')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($ly_addPost, 'Permission_id')->dropdownList([$ly_addPost->Permission_id]);?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Create' , ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

My controller has two create from from two different view one for post and another one for gallery

my controller code is :

```
public function actionView($id)
    {

        $ly_addPost = new Posts();
        $ly_addGallery = new Galleries();
        //$ly_addAudio = new Audios();
        //$ly_addVideo = new Videos();

        $ly_addPost->Channel_id = $id;
        $ly_addGallery->Channel_id = $id;

        $ly_addPost->Userid = Yii::$app->user->id;
        $ly_addGallery->Userid = Yii::$app->user->id;

        // for permission post
        $ly_addPost->Permission_id = Permission::find()
        ->select(['Permission_type'])
        ->indexBy('Permission_id')
        ->column();

        // for permission galery
        $ly_addGallery->Permission_id = Permission::find()
        ->select(['Permission_type'])
        ->indexBy('Permission_id')
        ->column();

        if ($ly_addPost->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {   

            $ly_addPost->Post_id = Yii::$app->params['ly_randCttid'];
            $ly_addPost->Post_uid = Yii::$app->params['ly_randCttid'];

            $ly_addPost->save();    

            return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findModel($id),
                'ly_addPost' => $ly_addPost,
                'ly_addGallery' => $ly_addGallery,
            ]);

            exit();
        }
        else if ($ly_addGallery->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {   

            $ly_addGallery_id = Yii::$app->params['ly_randCttid'];
            $ly_addGallery_uid = Yii::$app->params['ly_randCttid'];

            $ly_addGallery->save(); 

            return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findModel($id),
                'ly_addPost' => $ly_addPost,
                'ly_addGallery' => $ly_addGallery,
            ]);

            exit();
        } else {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'ly_addPost' => $ly_addPost,
            'ly_addGallery' => $ly_addGallery,
        ]);
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to clear $ly_addPost before rendering

```
} else {


    foreach ($ly_addPost as $key => $value) {
        $ly_addPost->$key = null;  //set to null instead of unsetting
    } // this foreach clear all variable of   $ly_addPost;

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'ly_addPost' => $ly_addPost,
            'ly_addGallery' => $ly_addGallery,
        ]);
}
```

Comment: I get this error after I used your code:Undefined variable: propery
 in I:\zzerver\Uwamp -port 84\uw-cms-p8585\www\yii28\controllers\ChannelController.php

Comment: @Bynd oops sorry for my mistake check  it out , I edited it .

Comment: it's clear the form now but if I refresh the page it's insert again the same data enered before to the database

Comment: @Bynd  put my foreach before all your renders , it will works 100%

Comment: it's still the same if I refresh the page it's insert the data to database

Comment: @Bynd dear sir check your code you always init ly_posts with user id  and id from function parameter you have to move all init lines such as li_post->chandelid , user id and other to if(li_post load )

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by changing

```
return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findModel($id),
                'ly_addPost' => $ly_addPost,
                'ly_addGallery' => $ly_addGallery,
            ]);

            exit();
```

To

```
return $this->refresh();
```

Now my code in controller is

```
if ($ly_addPost->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {   

            $ly_addPost->Post_id = Yii::$app->params['ly_randCttid'];
            $ly_addPost->Post_uid = Yii::$app->params['ly_randCttid'];

            $ly_addPost->save();    

            return $this->refresh();
        }
```